# Strange NameError: name 'math' is not defined, while "import math"

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, nameerror

I receive NameError while executing this code. It is weird because there is import math in the code. There is import math in sigma module...Maybe it is kind of a conflict?
Thanks for your time!

```
  File "C:\Users\Greenman\Documents\Python Scripts\sigma_crit.py", line 21, in sigma_crit
    # Simplified MC

NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

---

```
import sigma as sgm # Module sigma has "import math" as well
import math
def sigma_crit(sigmaX, sigmaY, sigmaZ, Theta, Pw, Pres, nu, alpha, No):
    """
    Return value of critical stress calculated for one of three failure criterias.
    No: 1 - Simplified Mohr-Coulomb
        2 - Mohr-Coulomb
        3 - Drucker-Prager
        4 - list with 3 model's resutls
    sigmaX - stress at X wellbore axis
    sigmaY - stress at Y wellbore axis
    Theta - azimuth,anticlokwise from SH_max
    nu - Poisson's ratio
    alpha - Biot's  coefficient
    """ 
    sigma_theta = sgm.sigma_calc(sigmaX, sigmaY, sigmaZ, Theta, Pw, Pres, nu, alpha, 1)
    sigma_zi = sgm.sigma_calc(sigmaX, sigmaY, sigmaZ, Theta, Pw, Pres, nu, alpha, 2)
    sigma_thzi = sgm.sigma_calc(sigmaX, sigmaY, sigmaZ, Theta, Pw, Pres, nu, alpha,3)
    # Conerting degrees to radians for below equations...Caution above functions has built-in converter
    Theta = math.radians(Theta)
    # Simplified MC
```

Comment: Upvoted for including the traceback, which contains the answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running *stale bytecode*. You changed the source file but did not restart Python.

You can see this from the traceback; the traceback is generated by reading the source file and taking embedded line number information from the bytecode being run to show the corresponding line in the source.

But your traceback shows the comment on the *next* line; the bytecode reference is clearly outdated and you altered the code since.

Answer (score -1):

The same error occurs to me, and the following operation works for me:

change

```
import math
```

to

```
from math import sqrt, ceil
```

So I think you can separately import the function you want to use from math.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This change would most definitely *not* fix an error that ``math`` is not defined. In fact it purposely removes defining the name ``math``.